# systemd-analyze does not detect changes made by systemctl edit

Tags: systemd, security, systemctl

I am hardening my existing systemd services for Ubuntu 20.04 as recommended by a Lynis audit using `systemd-analyze`.  I would like to use `systemctl edit` to make the changes, but `systemd-analyze` does not detect them, but rather only detects them if I directly edit the service file.  Is there any way to link the /etc/systemd/system/*my_service*.service.d/ results to the main service file so that `systemd-analyze` would know about the changes?

Ad nauseam, what I am doing is as follows:

```
sudo lynis audit system
```

which complains:

```
[+] Boot and services
------------------------------------
...
  - Check running services (systemctl)                        [ DONE ]
        Result: found 42 running services
  - Check enabled services at boot (systemctl)                [ DONE ]
        Result: found 70 enabled services
  - Check startup files (permissions)                         [ OK ]
  - Running 'systemd-analyze security'
   ...
        - accounts-daemon.service:                            [ UNSAFE ]
...
  Suggestions (24):
  ----------------------------
  * Consider hardening system services [BOOT-5264] 
    - Details  : Run '/usr/bin/systemd-analyze security SERVICE' for each service
      https://cisofy.com/lynis/controls/BOOT-5264/
...
```

So, I run the following:

```
systemd-analyze security accounts-daemon.service
```

which outputs the following:

```
  NAME                                                        DESCRIPTION                       >
✗ PrivateNetwork=                                             Service has access to the host's network  >
✗ User=/DynamicUser=                                          Service runs as root user                 >
...
→ Overall exposure level for accounts-daemon.service: 9.6 UNSAFE
```

Now, if I edit as follows:

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service
```

and I add the suggestions from Ruderich (2020) just above the `[Install]` line.  Then I run the following

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
systemd-analyze security accounts-daemon.service
```

and the result from systemd-analyze is as follows:

```
→ Overall exposure level for accounts-daemon.service: 1.2 OK
```

However, if, instead of editing the file directly (`sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service`), I run the following:

```
sudo systemctl edit accounts-daemon
```

or

```
sudo systemctl edit --full accounts-daemon
```

and make the edits that way, the output from the following:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
systemd-analyze security accounts-daemon.service
```

does not change from the first, pre-edit analysis, as follows:

```
→ Overall exposure level for accounts-daemon.service: 9.6 UNSAFE
```

In closing, I assume that `systemd-analyze` only checks the file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service` and ignores the files in `/etc/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service.d/` created by `systemctl edit`.  If this is the case, don't know enough about how `systemctl edit` works or how linking works to fix the problem.

Reference:
Ruderich, S. (2020, January 25). Systemd service hardening. Retrieved from https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/systemd-service-hardening

Comment: Can you give an example? I just checked one of the services I edited (added `Umask=0027`) and `systemd-analyze security service_name` made a comment about files created are group-readable.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I've added exactly what I'm doing in the main post.  Are you doing the same thing and getting good output?

Comment: When I edited the `foldingathome.service`, it created an override file here: `/etc/systemd/system/foldingathome.service.d/override.conf. There are no other files in that directory.